# Adding a multicast route to the linux multicast routing table

Tags: linux, multicast

I want to add an IPv4 multicast route say 225.0.0.9 to the **multicast routing table** of Linux. Is it possible to do so using any C program code? Any existing application this performs this task would also work.
I've found numerous posts that add a multicast route to the unicast routing table using command *route add 225.0.0.9 dev eth0* but this is not what I really want.
Please provide any directions or clarifications for the same.

Answer (score 0):

The hard way to manipulate route and mroute table is by using the rtnetlink API. This is not something I recommend if you only need this single function, since that API can be tricky if you are inexperienced with playing with pointers and structs wrapped into each-other.

The easier way is to just fork out a helper process and execute `ip` commands, since `ip` implements all of the features you need via command-line.

Comment: man page of ip-mroute states _Due to the limitations of the current interface to the multicast routing engine, it is impossible to change mroute objects administratively, so we can only display them.  This limitation will be removed in the future._  Is it possible to program mroute using netlink API's? Could you please provide some reference links.

Comment: The bigger question I should probably ask is what do you want to actually achieve, what is the actual use case? Since if you want to forward multicast packages from one device to another, you would need more than just a routing table due to IGMP. The mroute table should in general be maintained from something intelligent like mrouted. https://delog.wordpress.com/2014/11/26/enable-ip-multicast-routing-in-linux-kernel/ https://github.com/troglobit/mrouted